# Removing Samba Error

Tags: apt, package-management, samba, uninstall, shared-library

I am having a problem with Samba package. So I did the following to remove it, and got some errors.

```
# sudo apt-get --purge remove samba-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  samba* samba-common* samba-common-bin*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 42.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 195751 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing samba ...
Purging configuration files for samba ...
Removing configuration file /etc/default/samba...
Removing configuration file /etc/default/samba...
Removing samba-common-bin ...
Removing samba-common ...
Purging configuration files for samba-common ...
**perl: error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so.5.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing samba-common (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Processing triggers for man-db ...
perl: error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so.5.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for ufw ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba-common**
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you remove any files manually, before trying out the above command?

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo apt-get autoremove` and then `sudo apt-get purge samba*`.

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands in terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install perl
sudo apt-get purge samba*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail, to the questioner, as to what these four commands do?  This may be their solution, but it would help them grow to know how/why this solves it.